# When creating a template in whatsapp cloud api it is always rejected

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, postman, whatsapp

I am trying to create a template from postman by sending this object:

```
{
    "name": "listado_productos",
    "language": "es",
    "category": "TRANSACTIONAL",
    "components": [
        {
            "type" : "HEADER",
            "format": "document",
            "example": {
                "header_handle": [
                    "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CcTpDZL3p0ltMFhIKU9Vhz1LWG0bQFpN/view?usp=share_link"
                ]}
        },
        {
            "type": "BODY",
            "text": "Buenas tardes, acá le enviamos el nuevo listado de precios. Muchas gracias"
        },
        {
            "type": "FOOTER",
            "text": "ABS."
        }
    ]
}
```

If I [try an example from the official business-management-api guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/business-management-api/message-templates/), it also rejects it for non-compliance with terms and conditions.

```
"name": "promotional_message",
  "language": "en_US",
  "category": "TRANSACTIONAL",
  "components": [{
           "type":"BODY",
           "text":"Hi {{1}}, get an extra 10% off every order above $300.",
           "example":{"body_text":[["Sonia"]]}
         },
         {
           "type":"HEADER",
           "format":"TEXT",
           "text": "Bonus Tuesday starts now!"
         },
         {
           "type":"FOOTER",
           "text":"Not interested? Tap Stop promotions"
         },
         {
           "type":"BUTTONS",
           "buttons":[{"type":"QUICK_REPLY", "text": "Shop now"},
            {"type":"QUICK_REPLY", "text": "Stop promotions"}]
         }]
```

The response is that it is rejected for being duplicate or not complying with WhatsApp Busiess Api terms and services but it is not true, I read the terms and conditions and the file / message format complies. Does anyone identify the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`example.header_handle` has to be a handle generated using [Facebook Resumable Upload API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/guides/upload/):

(Pseudo-code follows)

```
uploadSessionId = POST https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/535136398713733/uploads?
    file_length={fileSize}&
    file_type={fileMimeType}&
    access_token={accessToken}

handle = POST https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/{uploadSessionId} 
    with header["Authorization"] = "OAuth {accessToken}"
    with body = {fileContent}

...
{
    "type" : "HEADER",
    "format": "document",
    "example": {
        "header_handle": ["{handle}"]}
    }
}
```

(As a side note, using the documented `example.header_url` (instead of `example.header_handle`) causes *Internal Server Error* on Facebook side).